# NSError returns self

Tags: ios, error-handling

I have a weird problem.

I am declaring an NSError :

```
 NSError *error;
```

Right after that I am checking for the error and I get the "self" class.

```
 NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
```

And the result :

> 2012-07-07 20:48:55.489 JerusalemBiblicalZoo[54204:1e407] Error:
>   ParseHelper

Any Ideas ?

Tanks

Shani

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Saying `NSError *error;` just declares a pointer to an error object. Unless you initialize it (such as with `NSError *error = nil`), it will be a random garbage value. (Which, in this case, is self.)

Comment: Thanks, that was indeed the problem. Will accept it in 10 minutes :)